# multipart/form-data not sending binary data in header

Tags: html, http, upload, multipartform-data

I am wondering why this code is not sending the file's data in the HTTP request header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.html" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="photo">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is not pointing at any server side code however to my knowledge this shouldn't affect the browser generating the HTTP request. Looking at the actual HTTP request it shows that it is getting the filename but not the actual data. The link below shows the request payload in chrome.

[Request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK08g.png)

Comment: Body, not header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sending the file data. Chrome Dev tools just doesn't show it.